# Understanding the use of the [education] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-reorganization

What's the use of the [education](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) tag, given that we have the [learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) and [teaching](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) tags?

Comment: What is the scope of [learning] tag is not clear to me *at all*, by the way. Is it supposed to be smth close to [self-study] or rather to [machine-learning]? Looks like a garbage tag to me.

Comment: @amoeba same here

Comment: Only `[teaching]` even has an excerpt. Probably we should figure out what we want the other two to mean / be used for, create excerpts, & make them synonyms or destroy them, etc.

Comment: Update: issue resolved (see update to Andre's answer), answer ready for acceptance :-)

Comment: @amoeba Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:**

[learning] - **done**.
[education] - **done**.

---

Some users consider these to be meta tags, therefore, not to so great tags.

Taking into account comments from @amoeba's and @gung's, the revised proposal is:

1. [learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) and [education](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education):

   - remove tags; take advantage of edits to perform full revisions (set tags properly, typos, readability, title, etc.)
2. [teaching](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching):

   - leave it as it is.

Comment: I disagree with point 1.3: I think [learning] is such a confusing tag name that we should not make it a synonym of anything but rather eliminate this tag. It seems that in most cases it refers to machine learning or to "learning" a model; this can be removed or retagged to machine-learning if needed. A minority of threads might need to be retagged into teaching or self-study.

Comment: Also, I don't quite see why e.g. [teaching] is a meta tag. Teaching of statistics is on-topic here and questions about teaching deserve their own tag. I wouldn't say it's a "bad" tag.

Comment: I think `[education]` would be best to be removed entirely, rather than made a synonym. For `[learning]`, where it means 'learning a model', we might be able to substitute `[estimation]` or `[fitting]` (I'm not sure if those should be synonyms.

Comment: I don't like the self study tag.  I think it should apply only to homework and therefore get rid of it. What is the difference between an ordinary tag and a meta tag?  Users can create their own tags regardless of what is suggested.  So isn't the process of cleaning up tags a never ending battle? I think the education tag is meaningless.  Everything we do on this site is intended to further educate.  For CV I think the learning tag is a problem since machine learning is a major topic and the learning tag can be confused with machine learning tag.

Comment: @AndreSilva Thank you for answering my somewhat naive questions. I am going to read your post to see what the argument is for keeping self study.

Comment: I went through that post.  It was very long with long answers and too much discussion.  But the bottom line for me is that questions that are not homework are too subjectively labelled self study.  In my recent activity on the CV site I have found that the OP does not initially label the question "self study" and a moderator or other user makes the judgment (very subjectively) that the question needs the self study tag. If the OP doesn't add the tag one of three things will happen (1) someone other than the OP adds the tag (2) the OP dutifully adds the tag (3) the tag never gets added.

Comment: Most of the time regardless as to which of these three outcomes occur, things end up bad for the OP.  If he wanted an answer he doesn't get one. If he only gets hints they may not be helpful enough.  Otherwise he gets no satisfactory help and his question is closed or deleted.  These questions are not homework or exam questions and I think the OP deserve an answer if the question is acceptable and someone could provide a reasonable answer. If the self study tag were eliminated none of these difficulties would occur.  Someone might see pitfalls but I don't.

Comment: Re your update: Five threads are going to be automatically deleted very soon because they are closed/downvoted (I have no downvoted some of the questions/answers to enable automatic deletion). If you downvote http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180284 it will also be erased (I already downvoted). So this will be 6. The other two are closed as duplicate and I think should be edited to remove the [learning] tag.

Comment: Looking at it again, why don't we make education a synonym of teaching instead of retagging?

Comment: Andre, I have no idea, I did not really look. To me the tag name "education" sounds like it should be synonymous with "teaching", but perhaps in practice it's not always like that. One option is to retag all threads that do not fit [teaching] scope, and then to decide if we make a synonym or retag the rest into [teaching].

Comment: Well done. So do you think we should make [education]->[teaching] synonym for the future, or rather not?

Comment: Tks @amoeba (for the comment and help getting this done). What I observed was that not all questions tagged [education] were about [teaching] (they were also about learning/self-study and career). I'd suggest wait and see if [education] pops up again. If it does, we can come back to this discussion to define a synonym.