# Can we ask questions related to deep learning/AI?

Tags: discussion

> This question appears to be off-topic because EITHER is not about statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, or data visualization, OR it focuses on programming, debugging, or performing routine operations within a statistical computing platform. If the latter, you could try the support links we maintain.

This states that we are supposed to ask questions related to `statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, or data visualization`.

Are we supposed to ask questions related to deep learning/AI?

Comment: And we have ai stackexchange and data science stack exchange so it can be confusing. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Deep learning is a subtopic within machine learning, which is on topic.  Deep learning is just, um, deeper than regular machine learning.  Note that we have an active tag, [deep-belief-networks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-belief-networks), that pertains to deep learning with 89 threads.  We have also had tags for `[deep-learning]` and `[deep-rl]` that are now mapped to [neural-networks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neural-networks) and [reinforcement-learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinforcement-learning).  That doesn't mean that those topics became off limits, just that, e.g., deep learning is now nearly synonymous with neural networks and it isn't useful for us to maintain distinct tags from the perspective of organizing the information on the site.  I also [find](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Adeep+is%3Aquestion+) 631 questions with "deep" in the title, of which 90% are not closed.

Artificial intelligence is somewhat trickier.  We do have an [artificial-intelligence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) tag that hosts 229 threads.  However, AI is a broader topic than machine learning, rather than a subset.  There are aspects of AI that would not fall within our scope.  In addition, there is an [artificial intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) SE site, where such questions (even the broader ones) can be asked and might find a better audience.

Comment: Great answer.  I think the reason it's called *deep learning* rather than *deep architectures* is because it's easy to build a deep architecture.  The hard part is learning the parameters!  I think in the long run, the deep-learning tag shouldn't be mapped to neural networks, but it's true that deep neural networks are an example of a deep architecture.

Comment: @NeilG, there was a [question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5639/) last year about making `[deep-learning]` a synonym of `[neural-networks]`. The consensus was *yes* & it happened. The tags haven't been merged, so the synonym can be undone, but there was a big discussion & the result was fairly clear.